# How to get library names given package names in Java

Tags: java

package com.something.a.something

I would like to extract the name of the library of the above package name in JAVA. The library name would be something-a. Does anyone know how do I identify the library name from a package name given the above statement?

Comment: Does the "something" of "something-a" come from the first or the second "something" in the package name?

Comment: What is a "library name"? If it is the name of the jar file or of a Maven artefact, then there are no fixed or standard rules how that relates to the package name.

Comment: The best I think you could do would be to Google the package name and see if you can find a link to a page with the corresponding JAR.  E.g. Google `com.something.a.something JAR`

Comment: Let me refine my question with the following package name

"edu.stanford.nlp.process.ptbtokenizer"

The above package name comes from the library "stanford-nlp". But how do I know if other package names contain such library names that contain hyphen rather than just "standford"? It will be too time consuming to do it manually as I have thousands of such package names

Comment: What are you really trying to do? Find which package comes from which "library" (whatever that is)? And why?

Comment: I'm trying to plot a scattered graph according to the packages in each library and each scattered graph represent a library which is something similar to t-SNE visualization